# Why doesn't the limit exist after changing the epsilon-delta definition?

Tags: epsilon-delta, function-and-relation-composition

Theres an example following a proof on the limit of a composite function in my book where the author tries to justify their use of $|x-x_0|<\delta$ rather than $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$ in the standard epsilon-delta definition;

Consider the functions $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} x\sin(\frac{1}{x}) &\text{if}\;x\neq0 \\0 &\text{if}\;x=0 \end{cases} \\ g(y)=\begin{cases}1  &\text{if}\;y\neq0 \\0  &\text{if}\;y=0 \end{cases}$$

Then with $|x-x_0|<\delta$ definition, $\lim_{y\to0}g(y)$ does not exist and the theorem of limit of composite function is vacuously true since the hypotheses (which includes that the above limit needs to exist) are not fulfilled. This part I understood.

But when we have $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$, the above limit (=1) and $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0$ exists but the author states that $\lim_{x\to0}(g\circ f)(x)$ does not exist. How? Informally, if $x$ gets close to $0$, then $f(x)$ gets close to zero, so this "close to zero" value gets fed into $g$ which will hover around the value 1. So where do things go wrong?

Comment: The whole point of distinguishing between $0 < |x - x_0| < \delta$ and $|x - x_0| < \delta$ is to distinguish between a (finite) limit *existing* of some function $f(x)$, as $x \to x_0$, and $f(x)$ being *continuous* at $x = x_0$.

Comment: You can answer this question only by carefully working through what the two slightly different definitions say. Informal talk about closeness and hovering won't help.

Comment: I agree with the author.  The difficulty is that in any neighborhood around $x = 0$, there will be isolated values of $\sin(1/x)$ that are equal to $0$.  This disrupts the limit of $g\circ f$, as $x \to 0.$